Reading from MT6816 magnetic encoder with SPI connection using Python on Raspberry Pi 4
I am totally new to the field, don't really know what I'm doing and in need of help. I'm trying to read an absolute angle using a MT6816 14-bit magnetic encoder via SPI connection with Raspberry Pi.
I have the following question:

On the hardware side, is it simply just wiring up the necessary connections (3.3V, MOSI, MISO, SCK, GND, CE01)?

For the coding part, I'm using Thonny and it seems like spidev library is pre-installed as the 'Raspberry Pi SPI loopback test code'(https://gist.github.com/fnishio/b2063941b82f2cf1b935) ran without any error. Thus, I assumed no other setup is needed other that enabling SPI in raspi-config. Am I right? Or are there ways to test if SPI connection works?

To my understanding according to the MT6816 datasheet(https://www.compel.ru/item-pdf/c51a62edcf72a97fdb3c3d9108c3c3d5/pn/magntek~mt6816ct-std.pdf : page 23), what I need (i.e. the 14-bit angle data) is stored in the register addresses 0x03 and 0x04[7:2]. I have no idea how to access into said addresses and read those values.


I wired up the 6 wires and played around with the code(again didn't really know what I was doing). I moved the magnet around the sensor expecting swinging range of values, the output just switched back and forth between [0, 0, 0] and [255, 255, 255].
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.threewire = False
spi.mode = 3

def BytesToHex(Bytes):
    return ''.join(["0x%02X " % x for x in Bytes]).strip()

try:
    while True:
        resp = spi.xfer2([0x8300, 0x8400, 0x8500])
        #print(BytesToHex(resp))
        print(resp)
        time.sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    spi.close()
    print("Ctrl-C pressed")

I'm eager to learn a lot! I'll appreciate any help you can offer.

This question may yield more help over at Raspberry PI stackexchange where folks can speak to both the programming and the physical set up to help troubleshoot further.

I tried the same think with an Arduino and I got more or less the same.
Reading data I got either 0 or 16383.
#include <SPI.h>

const int CS_PIN = 10; // Chip Select pin
const byte READ_COMMAND = 0x83; // Read command with register address, assuming 0x03

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Set CS pin as output and deselect the sensor
  pinMode(CS_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);
  
  // Initialize SPI communication
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV16);  // Set SPI clock speed
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3);            // Set SPI mode (CPOL=1, CPHA=1)
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);             // Set bit order (Most Significant Bit First)
}

void loop() {
  // Read sensor data over SPI
  uint16_t angleData = readAngleData();
  
  // Print the sensor data to serial console
  Serial.print("Angle: ");
  Serial.println(angleData);
  
  // Wait for a bit before the next read
  delay(1000);
}

uint16_t readAngleData() {
  // Select the sensor
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, LOW);
  
  // Send read command for register 0x03 and 0x04
  SPI.transfer(READ_COMMAND);
  
  // Read two bytes of data from the sensor
  uint8_t highByte = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  uint8_t lowByte = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  
  // Deselect the sensor
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);
  
  // Combine the two bytes into a single 16-bit value
  uint16_t result = (highByte << 8) | lowByte;
  
  // Extract angle data
  uint16_t angle = (result & 0x3FFF); // 14-bit angle data
  
  return angle;
}


Mybe you can try change your READ_COMMAND to 0x8300, if you want to read register with address 0x03,the function code is bit 1 according to the datasheet.If you use READ_COMMAND with case 0x83, mybe this function is write logic according to the datasheet.

Anwers that start with maybe should either be posted as a command or rewritten to be conclusive. Once you earn enough reputation you'll be able to post comments

I guess you have version based on the board, not a pure chip.
So, if you want to use SPI you just should connect (solder) the R3 jumper. And the result will be completely amazing.
